# Javascript call function when another asynchronous function ends

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous

I have a function that realizes a few httprequest . I need to refresh the parent window and close the current window when all these requests art completed.
But now the current window is closing before completing the requests and the request are not finishing correctly.
Here's my code:

```
<script>
        function save()
        {

            $.when( insert() ).done(function() {
                opener.location.reload();
                window.close();
            });

        }

        function insert()
        {
            $('select').each(function () {
                var idTraslado = $(this).attr("id");
                var accion = $(this).val();

                //the page realizes mysql updates. 
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET","trasladosEliminarMultipleGuardar.php?idTraslado="+idTraslado+"&accion="+accion+"&motivo="+motivo,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: https://www.promisejs.org/ Did you search at least?

Comment: __Why__ are you doing raw `XMLHttpRequest` if you have jQuery?!

Comment: how could I do it with jquery ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ is the biggest reason to use jquery in the first place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use promises otherwise `when` has no use in your code:

```
function save()
{
    $.when(insert()).done(function () {
        opener.location.reload();
        window.close();
    });
}

function insert()
{
    var promises = [];
    $('select').each(function () {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var idTraslado = $(this).attr("id");
        var accion = $(this).val();

        //the page realizes mysql updates. 
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onload = function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "trasladosEliminarMultipleGuardar.php?idTraslado=" + idTraslado + "&accion=" + accion + "&motivo=" + motivo, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        promises.push(deferred.promise());
    });
    return promises;
}
```

Comment: isn't this going to be resolved when the first ajax request finishes ? what will happen to the rest ?

Comment: right! did not notice that, will edit with an aproach that will return an array of promises